# How to retrieve a DataSource from JBoss via JNDI

Tags: java, jdbc, jboss, jndi

What I am trying to do is to retrieve a DataSource from a locally running JBoss (EAP 5.1) per JNDI. 
It works fine inside a deployed DAO, but I seem to misunderstand something as when I am trying to get the DataSource in a test case, I keep getting a `javax.naming.NoInitialContextException` when trying

```
        Properties env = new Properties();
        env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "jnp://localhost:1099");

        final InitialContext ic = new InitialContext(env);
        ds = (DataSource) ic.lookup(DATASOURCE_NAME);
```

If i add

```
        env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory");
```

I get a `ClassNotFoundException` for the `org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory`

Being new to JNDI and JBoss, I'm stuck at that point. Searching the web just adds to my confusion as all I find are scattered pieces of info that I try to apply by trial-and-error with no real progress.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What functionality is it that you are testing? Is it the retrieval of a DataSource or some actual database code? If the latter, then I would suggest not using JNDI at all and using a local DataSource implementation.

This thread shows how to use Commons DBCP to set up local DataSources.

http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?16670-Problem-running-JUNIT-test-with-JNDI-datasource

If you really need the JNDI aspect, this example shows how to populate an InitialContext with a minimum of values to get a DataSource back. You can probably use the same Commons DBCP config as above to configure the DataSource(s) that you need.

http://blogs.oracle.com/randystuph/entry/injecting_jndi_datasources_for_junit

Comment: I tried to test some SQL statements. The local DS approach makes much more sense. Thank you.